# Cauchy integral formula with singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am stuck on this question.
$$\int \frac{e^{sin z^{2}}}{(z^{2}+1)(z-2i)^{3}}dz $$
along the path γ where γ is a circle centered at the origin of radius different from 1 or 2.
I initially thought of doing a partial fraction decomposition for the denominator but that doesn't seem possible. How can I tackle this question using only the cauchy integral formula and no other advanced theorems?
Thank you for reading my query.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the fact that on such a circle only goes around the poles with radius 1 from the origin corresponding to the term $z^2 + 1$ in the denominator but does not go around the pole with radius 2 from the origin corresponding to the term $(z - 2^i)^3$ in the denominator.

Then using the Cauchy integral formula, you can get a formula for the integral in terms of the function $f(z) = e^{sinz^2}$ in the numerator.

Let me know if you have further questions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: I wanted to know what happens if we take circles with radii greater than 2.In such a case there will be 3 singularities we would have to deal with.

Comment: That's correct, but the contour integral will also be equal to the sum of three contour integrals, each one around only one of the poles. See for example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/29/Cauchy-contour.png Thus in applications it almost always reduces to calculating the contour around each pole separately and then summing the values together.

Comment: Since there are imaginary poles, what happens when the poles are plugged into sin()? In other words, how can one interpret sin(i) in terms of conceptual understanding and problem-solving?

Comment: @mikey I would just try to use this consequence of Euler's formula $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, e^{i^2x} = e^{-x} = \cos(ix) + i \sin(ix) \implies \sin(ix) = \frac{e^{-x} - \cos(ix)}{i} = -i e^{-x} + i \cos(ix)$, (using formula's for hyperbolic sine/cosine might also turn out to be necessary) or, if that doesn't work,  use the Taylor/power series expansion of sine. To be honest I'm not quite sure how to better answer your question -- complex analysis is neither my strong suit nor my area of expertise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Hyperbolic_functions_for_complex_numbers  apparently according to the linked-to article $\cos(ix) = \cosh(x)$, so $\sin(ix) = -ie^{-x}+i\cosh(x)$. Also apparently according to Wikipedia, more directly we can write $\sin(ix) = i\sinh(x)$, so $\sin(i) = i \sinh(1)$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives a similar result. Though a few solutions I've had trouble deriving express the answers in terms of modified absolute value expressions without hyperbolic functions. Just looking for some insight, though I think your suggestion of expanding Taylor Series may cancel terms and may lead somewhere fruitful. Thanks.